# tensorflow neural network model based on mnist with two outputs

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I want to train a neural network with 12 inputs and 2 outputs. Here I have a simple tensorflow neural network that has two outputs. When I run the code it always consistently gives one output. That is, if the two outputs are labeled 'l1' and 'l2' the model always chooses 'l1' for its output. Is this a problem with my input (that it doesn't vary enough between 'l1' and 'l2') or is this a problem with choosing to use just two outputs? This is my question. If it's the latter, what do I do to remidy this? My model is supposed to detect skin tones in a photo. ('l1' = skin tone, 'l2' = not skin tone). I'm not sure this makes sense. It is adapted from the mnist example, but that code has ten outputs.

```
def nn_setup(self):
    input_num = 4 * 3
    mid_num = 3
    output_num = 2

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_num])
    W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([input_num, mid_num]))
    b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([mid_num]))

    y_mid = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W_1) + b_1)

    W_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([mid_num, output_num]))
    b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output_num]))
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y_mid, W_2) + b_2)

    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, output_num])

    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_))

    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy) 

    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    self.sess = tf.Session()
    self.sess.run(init)

    for i in range(1000):
        batch_xs, batch_ys = self.get_nn_next_train()
        self.sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    self.nn_test.images, self.nn_test.labels = self.get_nn_next_test()
    print(self.sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: self.nn_test.images, y_: self.nn_test.labels}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few "odd" things with your network, such as having softmax in your middle layer.

You have two major issues I can find with your implementation.

---

### 1. Weight initialisation

```
W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([input_num, mid_num]))

W_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([mid_num, output_num]))
```

This will initialise the weights to be identical. So they will have identical gradient values, and be changed at each step identically.

Effectively by doing this you have created a network with one neuron in each layer (which is then copied to create the layer matrix that you use).

Use a different initial value, it is usual to take a small random matrix like this:

```
W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_num, mid_num], stddev=0.5))
```

In general you will want a smaller standard deviation the larger your layers are. You don't have to do this for biases as well, but you can if you like.

This won't fix everything with your network, but it should at least start to calculate different values from input data and train a little.

---

### 2. Use of cost function

You have used this loss function incorrectly:

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
  tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_) )
```

. . . because `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` is designed to work with the *input* to softmax, not the output. So your cost function is incorrect. Instead you want to reference `y_logits` like this where currently you calculate `y`:

```
 y_logits = tf.matmul(y_mid, W_2) + b_2
 y = tf.nn.softmax(y_logits)
```

Then your cross-entropy would be

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
  tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_logits, y_) )
```

Comment: thank you. I'm trying this out now. as I test initially the results at least are not always the same. I think something is going right but I will know more concretely soon. thanks alot.

Comment: @DLiebman: It is likely that you have other things that could do with advice, simply because you are new to this and neural networks have a lot of details that need to go right before things work well - relevant as you are implementing at a relatively low level. If your initial problem is resolved, but you still have other issues, it is better to gather more information about those new problems and ask a brand new question.

Comment: am I supposed to do something with `y` then? It only gets used in `correct_prediction` ?

Comment: @DLiebman `y` is the variable used for prediction. In your script you test it. In production, it is the output of the network that you will use to classify new images.

Comment: This link is to my next question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41019116/tensorflow-nn-mnist-example-with-modified-layer-dimensions

Answer (score 0):

After the hidden layer initialization, you have calculated `softmax` of the logits for the hidden layer: `y_mid = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W_1) + b_1)`. In a classification problem, `softmax` should be applied to the values obtained from the output layer. Try something like: `y_mid = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,W_1) + b_1)` to compute the activations from the hidden layer and see if your classification improves. If that does not solve your problem, check for the population of 'l1' and 'l2' in your training data. If your training data is highly skewed towards 'l1', you will always get 'l1' as the output. You may consider minority-oversampling or undersampling techniques to resolve population imbalance problem.

Comment: I spotted that too - but it is not the cause of the OP's problem.

Comment: @NeilSlater Without seeing training data, you will not know the actual problem OP has. Also, hyperparameter optimization will be the next thing to do if population imbalance is not the problem. **One step at a time.**

Comment: Yes I agree, but the choice of softmax is not as much a problem as you suggest -  a network with softmax in the middle should work after a fashion, although it is an odd choice. The OP's network is not functioning at all.

Comment: @NeilSlater I agree. A biased classification output may be due to a number of underlying problems. Symmetry of weights was another one, which you have mentioned in your other comment. Learning rate of 0.5 also seems a bit high to me. I would use a smaller value (0.1 or smaller) with exponential decay.

Comment: ... and, I will still not use `softmax` as an activation function for a hidden layer.