# tensorflow nn mnist example with modified layer dimensions

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I modified this mnist example so that it has two outputs and a middle layer of 10 nodes. It doesn't work, giving me a .50 score all the time. I think it just picks one of the outputs and responds with that no matter what the input is. How could I fix this so that it actually does some learning? The outputs are supposed to represent 0 for 'skin tone' and 1 for 'no skin tone'. I use png input.

```
def nn_setup(self):
    input_num = 784 * 3 # like mnist but with three channels
    mid_num = 10
    output_num = 2

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_num])
    W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_num, mid_num], stddev=0.04))
    b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([mid_num], stddev=0.5))

    y_mid = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,W_1) + b_1)

    W_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([mid_num, output_num],stddev=0.4))
    b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([output_num],stddev=0.5))

    y_logits = tf.matmul(y_mid, W_2) + b_2
    y = tf.nn.softmax(y_logits)

    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, output_num])

    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_logits, y_))

    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy) 

    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    self.sess = tf.Session()
    self.sess.run(init)

    for i in range(1000): 
        batch_xs, batch_ys = self.get_nn_next_train()
        self.sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


    self.nn_test.images, self.nn_test.labels =  self.get_nn_next_test()
    print(self.sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: self.nn_test.images, y_: self.nn_test.labels}))
```

Comment: Could you show how you are processing input data inside `self.get_nn_next_train()` (and test version) - show enough that it is clear how the images are getting converted. Have you tried reducing the learning_rate? The value of 0.5 might be too high, try dropping it down to 0.1, 0.01 and 0.001 (yes really that low). Could you also clarify your batch size. Finally, you are not tracking the loss, so cannot see if training is reducing it over time. Have you tried displaying it (do you know how?)

Comment: Here's a gist that shows the implementation of the a `get_nn_next_train()` method. The code services three methods. This one is the default. https://gist.github.com/radiodee1/6a00fc92d72350e6b301e62b65b211ec . After initializing the weights and biases with smaller numbers I am getting a score of 0.62.

Comment: and here is a more complete listing of the model itself... https://gist.github.com/radiodee1/3f7bb0dcc466e175755b77ea8228a7ba . Please excuse the names of some of the variables. they make no sense some times.

Comment: I had a quick look, but there is far too much code there for me to analyse in a reasonable time. My concern would be that you may be using input features with too large a range (i.e. 0..255), when for a NN it is really important to have them in a small range (typically mean 0, std 1.0, but also mapping 0..255 to 00..1.0 (divide by 255.0) is ok). If you look at some of your `batch_y` contents, do they look like raw pixel values 0 to 255 or has the image loader scaled them for you?

Comment: Also, just an idea (so not an answer), try swapping `tf.nn.relu` to `tf.tanh` and maybe increase `mid_num` to e.g. 50 in addition. I'll explain why I suggested that in an answer if it works :-)

Comment: you are correct. they are 0 to 255. I'll try scaling them later

Comment: well, scaling the input totally doesn't work. using `tanh` and `mid_num` of 50 doesn't seem to work either. having a really low learning rate with the `mid_num` at 10 seems to work. in the loader prog I reject some values because of their range. that is probably helping. I think I can get results around 0.80 with those settings.

Comment: I'm surprised that scaling the input failed. Did you also ensure you were scaling the test inputs in the same way?

Comment: if I scale the inputs should I change the learning rate to something higher? I can try that?

Comment: The scale of learning rate, weight initialisations and input features all interact. If you've got this working with larger input features, maybe you won't gain much by juggling the numbers around again, I am not sure. However, in the general case with a NN, you will want the input features to be scaled to a well-defined range (typically to mean 0.0 standard deviation 1.0), as it has been shown beyond reasonable doubt to be an important factor affecting training success.